# Is it ok to use lambda callback method in an async handler

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have existing lambdas based off of a codebase which uses an async/await syntax. A new lambda layer was introduced recently, and the lambda handler was switched to a new method (H1) within the layer, which is more of a decorator around the old handler (H0).

This H1 doesn't seem to handle promise rejections well, and this is causing a few issues in the way how the error message is returned from the lambda.

One of the workarounds I was able to use to get around this was to use the callback method instead of returning a promise from H0. But I'm not quite sure if this can cause any issues down the line. I couldn't find any documentation that suggests otherwise.

If someone has more info regarding this, I'd appreciate the help. Thank you.

**Additional Info**: The layer is not maintained by us, and we do not have the option to modify the layer's code unfortunately.